# Blank space above table

Tags: html, space

I am getting space above my table when this html page is run by a particular browser:

```
<table>
<center>
<tr><th width="150" scope="col">
5/28 - 5:47 PM: <br><br> x <br> x</th> <td width=1000>y
</td></tr>
<br><br><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr><th width="150" scope="col">
5/16 - 12:59 AM: <br><br> z <br> z <br>z <br> z</th><td width=1000>y</td></tr>
<br><br><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th width="150" scope="col">
5/10 - 12:34 AM: <br><br>z <br>z<br>z</th><td width=1000>y</td></tr>
<br><br><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th width="150" scope="col">
5/8 - 4:47 PM: <br><br> z <br>z</th> <td width=1000> y</td></tr>
<br><br><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: which particular browser?

Answer (score 1):

This HTML is badly broken. You can't have tags or text inside your table but outside a TR. You have tags like CENTER and BR in that location. You should use a validator or a decent IDE, which would catch these problems.

With some formatting, your code is:

```
<table>
    <center> <!-- THIS IS INVALID -->
    <tr>
        <th width="150" scope="col">
            5/28 - 5:47 PM: <br><br> x <br> x
        </th>
        <td width=1000>y</td>
    </tr>
    <br><br><!-- THIS IS INVALID -->
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="150" scope="col">
            5/16 - 12:59 AM: <br><br> z <br> z <br>z <br> z
        </th>
        <td width=1000>y</td>
    </tr>
    <br><br><!-- THIS IS INVALID -->
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="150" scope="col">
            5/10 - 12:34 AM: <br><br>z <br>z<br>z
        </th>
        <td width=1000>y</td>
    </tr>
    <br><br><!-- THIS IS INVALID -->
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="150" scope="col">
            5/8 - 4:47 PM: <br><br> z <br>z
        </th>
        <td width=1000> y</td>
    </tr>
    <br><br><!-- THIS IS INVALID -->
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On top of that, your `CENTER` tag has no closing tag, and you really shouldn't be using CENTER, anyway.

You also have inconsistent numbers of child elements for your TRs; sometimes it's one, and sometimes it's two. This will cause inconsistent display unless you use a `colspan="2"` attribute on the lone children.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not well edited, you didn't close your `<center>` tag.
And to get rid of the extra spaces on top of your table, you should remove `<br>` tags between your `<tr>` elements

So instead of

```
<tr>
    <th width="150" scope="col">
        5/28 - 5:47 PM: <br><br> x <br> x
    </th>
    <td width=1000>y</td>
</tr>
<br><br>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

You should have

```
<tr>
    <th width="150" scope="col">
        5/28 - 5:47 PM: <br><br> x <br> x
    </th>
    <td width=1000>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```